# Maximum fetch calls? Unlimited?

Tags: react-native

I have thousands of photos to upload. I am starting all of the uploads in parallel. Does this affect bandwidth? Or does the platform (iOS/Android) queue it up?

Answer (score 1):

Uploading thousands of files at the same time won't be the best in the world and would be better to write something to maybe do 5 at a time or something of the sort.

As of bandwidth if you do upload thousands of photos at the same time then the rest of the phones internet will be almost unusable.

The platform wouldn't queue it up, but the app wouldn't get accepted in the first place as it would be against the platform guidelines.

Comment: Is there any documentation on this? I thought each app is limited to certain bandwidth.

Comment: @Noitidart Not that I could find

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I'm also searching for this.

Comment: @Noitidart No problem haha :) Let me know if you need anything else